Live Data from a Scale
I’m working on a project where I need to log real-time data from a weigh scale into an Excel sheet. The catch is that the data should only be logged when I click a specific cell in the Excel sheet. How can I achieve this functionality using python or scala any other method? Any guidance or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

I didn't get it. You say you'll click on a specific cell, and a log will be filled into this cell's row automatically?

either getting the live data come into scale in real time or by means of me clicking any cell and then data gets populated in that cell.

"click on a specific cell, and a log will be filled into this cell's" means you need a trigger. However, Python libraries do not support triggering actions based on cell clicks directly within Excel. So you can only get the live data directly using a serial communication. Is it ok for you? And can you provide the information about how you communicated scale and the computer, please?

i used serial connector. ie. RS232 DB9 to USB-A

First install the pyserial and openpyxl packages using pip:
pip install openpyxl pyserial

and then you can read the data and write data to an excel file using this Python script below. I tried to write it to a xlsx file. Port and baud rate may vary, change this accordingly please if you don't read any data:
import serial
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)

excel_file = 'weigh_data.xlsx'
try:
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=excel_file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    workbook.save(excel_file)
    
sheet = workbook.active


def log_to_excel(weight):
    next_row = sheet.max_row + 1
    sheet[f'A{next_row}'] = weight
    workbook.save(excel_file)


while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        weight_data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        log_to_excel(weight_data)
        print(f"weight: {weight_data}")
        time.sleep(1)  # I also put sleep to read data every second
    else:
        print("no data available from the scale")


ser.close()


can you mark the answer as solved the issue please if it's ok for you? @KojoOlivet
